# Typescript : Create a JSON API, with an item, containing JSON

Tags: arrays, json, typescript

I have a small problem, I am creating an API for my users, however, I have an error, when I have my JSON.

- I have a json data that should be in array (and contain its JSON correctly). However, in the array, I put it as a "{"name":}" string.

My code :

```
import { TRPCError } from "@trpc/server"

import {
  createTRPCRouter,
  protectedProcedure
} from "@/lib/server/trpc"

//import { UserUtils } from "@/lib/utils"

export const userRouter = createTRPCRouter({
  user: protectedProcedure.query(async ({ ctx }) => {
    if (ctx.session?.user.id) {
      // Vérifier si ctx.session et ctx.session.user existent
      const userInfo = await ctx.db.user.findUnique({
        where: { id: ctx.session.user.id },
        select: {
          data_json: true,
        },
      })

      return {
        code: 200,
        data: userInfo?.data_json,
      }
    } else {
      throw new TRPCError({
        code: "UNAUTHORIZED",
      })
    }
  }),
})
```

I'd like to have this rendering:

`{ "code": 200, "data":[ { "name": "Name", "text": "example text" } ] }`

Thank's

I test JSON.parse(), but i have this error :

```
Argument of type 'string | null | undefined' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'.
  Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'string'.ts(2345)
⚠ Error (TS2345)  | 
Argument of type string || null || undefined is not assignable to parameter of type string.
   

Type undefined is not assignable to type string
 .
(property) data_json: string | null | undefined
```

Thank's,

Comment: Typescript is complaining that the result of `findUnique` might be `null` or `undefined`. I assume this can happen if the database record cannot be found. You should handle this situation (perhaps by throwing an error)

Comment: There's no call to JSON.parse in the code you posted. What are you attempting to parse?

Answer (score 0):

The issue lies within your return statement, where `userInfo` can be null in the case that the db query doesn't find anything:

```js
// userInfo can be null from the findUnique call
const userInfo = await ctx.db.user.findUnique({
  where: { id: ctx.session.user.id },
  select: {
    data_json: true,
  },
})

return {
  code: 200,
  // the optional chain here will turn a null value into undefined so that you're not trying to access `data_json` on a value of null
  data: userInfo?.data_json,
}
```

To fix this you need to simply verify that your data exists before attempting to parse it:

```js
// assuming this is how you're consuming your API via tRPC
const value = await api.userRouter.user.query();

// if your value exists in your DB and thus your returned value from your API is not undefined, you can attempt to parse
const parsedValue = value ? JSON.parse(value) : null;
```